# C++ Finding Bugs in Code related to linked lists

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

There's 2 pieces of code that I can't seem to find the bug with. I know there is something wrong within these. One for each.

```
int pop()
{
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp = tail;
    tail->prev()->setNext(NULL);
    int tempV = temp->key();
    delete temp;
    return tempV;
}
```

The other piece of code is this:

```
int main()
{   
    Node* t = new Node(0,NULL);
    t = Node(1,t);
    t = Node(2,t);
    delete t;
}
```

I thought about the 2 pieces of code for a while. For the 1st piece of code, I think the error is that you shouldn't create the Node* temp on the heap with the keyword `new`. It should just be `Node* temp = tail`; I believe. Can anyone confirm that?

For the 2nd piece of code, I thought the error was that you don't need both

```
t = Node(1,t); 
t = Node(2,t);
```

EDIT::I'm sorry I made a mistake. It was supposed to be Node rather than node. My friend told me it has to do something with memory. It there a memory leak because of the multiple nodes being declared with new? Or do we need the new keyword for the last 2?

Thanks

Comment: What does `node(int, Node*)` do?

Comment: could you show the implementation of the `node()` function?

Answer (score 0):

When you pop the element, you need not create a "new" node. You have to remove the last element of the linked list - not create a new node.

For your second question, you do not need the

```
t = node(1,t)
t = node(2,t)
```

if the function returns the currently added node. 
But if the function returns the header of the linked list, it is required. It depends on how you write the `node` function.

Answer (score 0):

you are losing the value you new

```
Node* temp = new Node();  
temp = tail;               <-- you just lost the value you new'ed
```

then later you are deleting a different node

`tail->prev()->setNext(NULL);    <-- this line doesn't check that the value for prev() isn't` null

as to what is going on in main I would need to see more of the code for "node"

Answer (score 0):

Dinesh is correct in the first example. Here is a little more explanation.

```
Node* temp = new Node()
temp = tail;
```

results in a memory leak. the new node that was created is leaked when you overwrite temp to tail. The proper way to do it would be

```
Node * temp = tail;
```

In the second example its not clear what the node function does.  If you meant to write this:

```
int main()
{   
    Node* t = new Node(0,NULL);
    t = new Node(1,t);
    t = new Node(2,t);
    delete t;
}
```

The code would make more sense, it creates a linked list of three nodes containing 2, 1, 0 when listed from head to tail. It's hard to tell from the incomplete example.

Comment: Sorry about that. It actually is Node(1,t) but without the t. So does it need the new keyword?

Comment: In the second example it is a memory leak again. You are allocating memory for 3 Nodes with the new keyword but only freeing up the memory for one of them.  Also, don't forget to select an answer by clicking the outline of the checkmark next to the answer you feel is best.

Answer (score 0):

In `pop` you have a memory leak. You construct a `Node` on the heap and then immediately lose track of it, like inflating a balloon and letting it go:

```
Node* temp = new Node();
temp = tail;
```

But you also have a more serious problem: **you do not adjust `tail`.** When the function is finished, `tail` points to a region of memory where the last node used to be, and any attempt to dereference it will cause Undefined Behavior.

As for your second question, the code might be correct, and it might not. There's no way to tell unless/until you show us what `node(...)` does.